# Passing ViewModel ASP.NET MVC Using Ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'am trying to pass one of my ViewModel to my Ajax function , but unfortunately , when i go to Console in my browser i can see its just retrieving empty string like this > {CustomerNo: ""} instead of retrieving correct data something like this > {CustomerNo: "1234"}.can anyone please point me in the right direction!
thanks.

My Ajax function:

```
<input type="text" id="CustomerNo" />

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        let OrdreNo = window.localStorage.getItem("pgm");



        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://xxx/Account/OpenOrdersDetails/" + OrdreNo ,
            dataType: "json",


            success: function (result) {
                alert(result.CustomerNo);



            } //End of AJAX Success function


        });


    });
</script>
```

This is what i have in my JsonResult:

```
[Route("Account/OpenOrdersDetails/{OrdreNo?}")]
public JsonResult OpenOrdersDetails(string OrdreNo)
{

 var bla4 = (from sh in data_2.Sales_Header
                        join h in data_2.Sales_Line on sh.No_ equals h.Document_No_
                        join s in data_2.Salesperson_Purchasers on sh.Salesperson_Code equals s.Code
                        where sh.No_ == OrdreNo
                        && sh.Document_Type == 1
                        select new xxx.Ordre_Open_Details_VM.OrdreSingelLine
                        {

                            OrdrerNo = sh.No_,
                            CustomerNo = sh.Sell_to_Customer_No_,
 Ordredate = sh.Order_Date,}
});

  oodvm.OrdreDetailsSingleLines = bla4.FirstOrDefault();


            return Json(oodvm,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And this my ViewModel:

```
  public class Ordre_Open_Details_VM
    {   

public OrdreSingelLine OrdreDetailsSingleLines { get; set; }

public class OrdreSingelLine
        {


            public OrdreSingelLine()
            {

            }
            public OrdreSingelLine(string OrdrerNo, string CustomerNo, DateTime Ordredate)
            {


                this.OrdrerNo = OrdrerNo;
                this.CustomerNo = CustomerNo;
                this.Ordredate = Ordredate;


            }

            public string OrdrerNo { get; set; }
            public string CustomerNo { get; set; }
            public DateTime? Ordredate { get; set; }
}
```

Json Output:

```
{"OrdreDetailsSingleLines":{"OrdreNo":"111111","CustomerNo":"22222","Ordredate":"/Date(1525816800000)/"}}
```

Comment: Actually, what you're logging in your console is your value for OrdreSingleLine, which is coming from your javascript. That's _not_ the response from the server, it's a value from the CustomerNo field on your page, which presumably is blank. We don't know why that's blank. We don't know how/why/if it's supposed to be populated. Either way, that's nothing to do with your ajax call. If you want to see the response from the server, do `console.log(JSON.stringify(result));` instead.

Comment: BTW `failure: function (response) {

                alert(response.responseText);
            },` is redundant. There is no such option as "failure" recognised by jQuery's $.ajax method. You can see all the available options here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: And `data: JSON.stringify(OrdreSingelLine)` is also redundant. Your C# method already accepted the `OrdreNo` parameter from the URL, as per your Route attribute. There's no need to send any other data.

Comment: @ADyson when i use  console.log(JSON.stringify(result)); , it will be retrievie all data correct , but i want just CustomerNo from OrdreSingelLine ViewModel to show on page so how can i tell to my success function to retrievie  CustomerNo from OrdreSingelLine ViewModel ?!

Comment: You should retrieve `result` inside success function. `success: function (result) { alert(result); ...`

Comment: It's just a JavaScript object, so getting `result.CustomerNo` will do it. Just like any other object. `$("#CustomerNo").val(result.CustomerNo);` will place the value into the textbox, if that's what you're struggling with.

Comment: @ADyson . this what i did ,but i get undefined. var OrdreSingelLine = {

            CustomerNo : $("#CustomerNo ").val()

        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://xxx/Account/OpenOrdersDetails/" + OrdreNo,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
              
               
            $("#CustomerNo").val(result.CustomerNo);
                //alert(result.CustomerNo );
            
            },

Comment: in that case please show me your JSON (i.e. I mean show me the output of `console.log(JSON.stringify(result));`) . If the structure is different you'll have to use a different accessor. Do you understand how to access properties of JavaScript objects?

Comment: BTW your line `var OrdreSingelLine = { CustomerNo : $("#CustomerNo ").val() };` is also redundant, it has no useful purpose. You never use `OrdreSingleLine` for anything important.

Comment: @ADyson i just added Json output to question :)

Comment: `$("#CustomerNo").val(result.OrdreDetailsSingleLines.CustomerNo);` . I assume you don't understand the structure of the object or else this would have been trivially obvious, It's probably something you should learn if you want to work with JavaScript and JSON

Comment: @ADyson i just did , thanks Adyson. it works :) i dont know why my question get -1 . i did nothing wrong , but if you like , post as answer and than i mark as right answer.

Comment: I don't know either, it wasn't me. If you hover over the vote buttons on any question you can see the reasons for which votes are supposed to be given. I will write an answer now, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the customer number from the response JSON and place it in your textbox, you can simply write (inside your "success" callback):

```
$("#CustomerNo").val(result.OrdreDetailsSingleLines.CustomerNo);
```